# Universal Image Loader smooth fade in

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I am using the UIL library to display local images. It works properly, though I want to do a smooth fade in effect. I have found this example here:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/commit/9939295afd32f7bb3016450453cb923ed166e533

Though, it is not smooth enough. I was checking out the audio player app called Pulsar and it does something very smooth. First it shows the no-cover icons for 300-500ms then fades into the real cover art. I wonder if this can be accomplished using UIL.

Thanks.